# Convert XML to JSON with additional id added in between

Tags: xml, json, mule, esb

I am using Mule ESB 3.5 and this is what I am trying to do:

XML -> convert it into an Object -> Enrich this object with an id -> transform it into JSON.
For this I am Using XML to Object and Object to Json components.
What should be the best way to populate the object with a transactionId before transforming it into the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert directly to JSON then use the JavaScript component to insert the value. This may be possible in MEL but I don't think so. Here's a simple flow that inserts transactionId field into the first element in the JSON array. Should give you an idea on how you could do it.

```
<flow name="xmltojsontransformerFlow1" doc:name="xmltojsontransformerFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="job"
                             repeatInterval="0" repeatCount="0" startDelay="300" responseTimeout="10000"
                             doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job />
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <parse-template
            location="/Users/tjs/MuleStudio/workspace3/xmltojsontransformer/src/main/resources/cd_catalog.xml"
            doc:name="Parse Template" />
    <custom-transformer class="cc.notsoclever.mule.XmlToJsonTransformer"
                        doc:name="XmlToJson" />
    <scripting:component doc:name="JavaScript">
        <scripting:script engine="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
json = JSON.parse(payload);
json[0].transactionId = "ABC123";
payload = JSON.stringify(json);]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

The above uses the transformer example I wrote for

[Mule: Is there simple way of converting XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722533/mule-is-there-simple-way-of-converting-xml-to-json)

Comment: I used a custom transformer for the same. Thanks

Comment: I need to try your approach, before I mark it is as answer