# How do I retrieve XML remotely and output it as JSON?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm completely new to Mule and I'm trying to put together a system to retrieve an XML file from a remote server and either display it as is or to convert it to JSON and then display it like that. What I have at the moment is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <flow name="TestFlow1" doc:name="TestFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="type" value="#[message.inboundProperties['type']]" doc:name="Set type variable"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="[URL REMOVED]" port="80" path="#[message.inboundProperties['feed']].php" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" ><response><object-to-string-transformer /></response></http:outbound-endpoint>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[flowVars['type']=='JSON']">
                <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[flowVars['type']=='xml']">
                <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer acceptMuleMessage="true" doc:name="Object to XML"/>
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="XML"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-payload value="Type not set" doc:name="Error message"/> 
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Retrieving the XML and displaying it as-is works just fine. I just need to figure out the JSON conversion.

I tried putting in an HTTP-to-Object transformer before the Object-to-JSON transformer, but that throws an illegal argument exception because the http:outbound-endpoint returns a response of class ReleasingInputStream. I've tried converting the response to a string and work with that, but that didn't work either.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Check this out. This explains who to transform the XML to JSON. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722533/mule-is-there-simple-way-of-converting-xml-to-json/20755504#20755504

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I have put posted my comment as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. This explains who to transform the XML to JSON.

[Mule: Is there simple way of converting XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722533/mule-is-there-simple-way-of-converting-xml-to-json/20755504#20755504)