# is there any way to convert xml to json with out using java code in mule esb?

Tags: xml, json, mule

I am able to convert xml to json using java code using following link,
[Mule: Is there simple way of converting XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722533/mule-is-there-simple-way-of-converting-xml-to-json/20755504#20755504)

but my requirement is n xml files has to covert one json format with out using java classes,how to do it?can you please help me???

Answer (score 2):

Just use XML To Json Transformer in Mule ... Please go through this docs :-
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Transformers

The tag is somewhat like this :- `<json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XmlToJson">` in your mule config

Answer (score 0):

You can use Smooks to make conversions between most common data formats. Take a look at this example: http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/using-smooksmule-to-transform-csv-file-to-xml-one/

Answer (score 0):

For automatic conversion where you don't care about the schema you can use the xml to json transformer. For finer grained control, the DataMapper in Mule Studio provides a graphical way to specify conversions from XML to JSON and vice versa. It has full support for detecting the Schema of the messages and implementing more sophisticated transformation rules using Mule Expressions in necessary.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference