# How to create a SOAP message from JSON payload in mule

Tags: soap, mule

I need to transform the following json payload into a soap message and send the message to a consumer, the consumer edits the data and sends back the soap message.

I haven't done much in soap. I only have REST experience. what steps do I need to take in a process like this?

what is the best approach?

```
[{"salesOrderId":"00004-5-6","saleName":"House Sale","status":"processing"}, {"salesOrderId":"00001-2-3","saleName":"Car Sale","status":"processing"}]
```

Comment: What lang are you doing this in?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am doing it in Mule. which is java based

Comment: Not familiar with Mule but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722533/mule-is-there-simple-way-of-converting-xml-to-json) transforms XML->JSON. Maybe `json.transformers` is what you need? There is a class `JsonToXml` as well [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/json/transformers/JsonToXml.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way of doing it is extract the **JSON** elements from the **JSON** payload by using `<json:json-to-object-transformer/>`and store each node value in variables like flow variable in Mule.
Then You can create the SOAP request using **XSLT** and passing the flow variables value into **XSLT** as `<mulexml:context-property/>`
ref:- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XSLT+Transformer
Once your **SOAP XML** is created, you can simply post them to your **HTTP** outbound endpoint pointing to your external web service you need to consume

Answer (score 3):

There are various way to perform this transformation, for example:

**PATH - 1**

- Json To XML (with transformer or string set payload)
- Xml To SOAP Request using XSLT, transformer or string set payload.
- Send SOAP Request sobre HTTP (POST / Content-type: applicacion/xml / soapAction)

**PATH - 2**

- Json To SOAP Request using Groovy, XSLT or string set payload.
- Send SOAP Request sobre HTTP-OUTBOUND (POST / Content-type: applicacion/xml / soapAction)

**PATH - 3**

- Json To SOAP Request Proxy (WSDL To Java).
- Send SOAP Request sobre HTTP-OUTBOUND (POST / Content-type: applicacion/xml / soapAction)

Comment: thanks for the reply, if i am using path-2, and i have transformed the json payload to xml. do i have to create a wsdl? or does mule do it for me

Comment: 1)get the WSDL associated with the service, 2) Use soapUI to consume it, 3) Take the SOAP Request as a base and fill with json or other variables, 4) Send Request via HTTP SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Mule DataMapper. That helps you to convert a JSON to XML in the more easier way. You can try it in Anypoint Studio of Mule.